# View hanging in final select - Leading to db forcefully stoppingthe query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

/edit - Changed the title to more appropriately match the problem.

Hi i have been sitting with a view this past week, which im told have been working in the past, but now stalls until Oracle automatically kills the procedure.

The view is running fine creating the two tmp tables in the two with statements. It is also running in the final select, up until the last few columns in the select statement. I have marked that point in the code snippet with a -- comment.

If I uncomment all but one random line in the last select. The code will run, but if i add one or more of the columns back in, the view will stall.

/Edit
Also if i replace the With bll_tbl with a static tmp table, im able to monitor that the query does indeed run (at least the the new tmp table) but very very slowly, it add rows in an increment of 100. and it takes about 30 sec to add each 100 rows. been running for 6 minutes now, and have added 1200 rows. Problem is that the total number of rows is properly in the 100k's.

Any suggestion to optimise the query ?

```
     , NVL(b.bucket_1_30, 0) AS bucket_1_30
     , NVL(b.bucket_31_60, 0) AS bucket_31_60
     , NVL(b.bucket_61_90, 0) AS bucket_61_90
     , NVL(b.bucket_91_180, 0) AS bucket_91_180
     , NVL(b.bucket_181_365, 0) AS bucket_181_365
     , NVL(b.bucket_over_365, 0) AS bucket_over_365
```

```sql
WITH acct_tbl
         AS (SELECT   acct_id
                    , NVL(
                          (SELECT SUM(amount)                                                     -- - advanced payments
                             FROM table1 p
                            WHERE p.acct_id = a.acct_id)
                        , 0)
                          AS advanced_payment
                    ,   NVL(                                                                        -- unbilled from MDB
                            (SELECT NVL(SUM(primal_fee), 0) + NVL(SUM(tax_fee), 0)
                               FROM tablex md
                              WHERE md.acct_id = a.acct_id)
                          , 0)
                      + NVL(                                                                         -- next bill credit
                            (SELECT SUM(adjust_fee)
                               FROM table2 brb
                              WHERE brb.acct_id = a.acct_id
                                AND adjust_type = 0                                                         -- next bill
                                AND EXISTS                                 -- is pending when created after last invoice
                                        (SELECT NULL
                                           FROM table3 ii
                                          WHERE ii.acct_id = brb.acct_id
                                            AND brb.so_Date > ii.end_date
                                            AND ii.rnk = 1                                               -- last invoice
                                                          ))
                          , 0)
                          AS unbilled
                 FROM table4 a
             GROUP BY acct_id)
       , bll_tbl
         AS (SELECT   acct_id
                    , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN bill_Fee > 0
                               AND due_date < SYSDATE
                              THEN
                                  unpay_Fee
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END)
                          AS billed_past_due
                    , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN bill_Fee > 0
                               AND due_date > SYSDATE
                              THEN
                                  unpay_Fee
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END)
                          AS billed_not_due
                    , SUM(CASE WHEN bill_fee < 0 THEN unpay_fee ELSE 0 END)                   -- credit amount from bill
                                                                           AS advanced_payment
                    , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN bill_Fee > 0
                               AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - due_date BETWEEN 1 AND 30
                              THEN
                                  unpay_Fee
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END)
                          AS bucket_1_30
                    , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN bill_Fee > 0
                               AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - due_date BETWEEN 31 AND 60
                              THEN
                                  unpay_Fee
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END)
                          AS bucket_31_60
                    , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN bill_Fee > 0
                               AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - due_date BETWEEN 61 AND 90
                              THEN
                                  unpay_Fee
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END)
                          AS bucket_61_90
                    , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN bill_Fee > 0
                               AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - due_date BETWEEN 91 AND 180
                              THEN
                                  unpay_Fee
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END)
                          AS bucket_91_180
                    , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN bill_Fee > 0
                               AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - due_date BETWEEN 181 AND 365
                              THEN
                                  unpay_Fee
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END)
                          AS bucket_181_365
                    , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN bill_Fee > 0
                               AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - due_date > 365
                              THEN
                                  unpay_Fee
                              ELSE
                                  0
                          END)
                          AS bucket_over_365
                 FROM table5 b
             GROUP BY acct_id)
    SELECT a.acct_id
         , NVL(b.billed_past_due, 0) AS billed_past_due
         , NVL(b.billed_not_due, 0) AS billed_not_due
         , NVL(b.advanced_payment, 0) - a.advanced_payment AS advanced_payment
         , NVL(b.billed_past_due, 0) + NVL(b.billed_not_due, 0) + (NVL(b.advanced_payment, 0) - a.advanced_payment)
               AS ar_balance
         , a.unbilled
         ,   NVL(b.billed_past_due, 0)
           + NVL(b.billed_not_due, 0)
           + (NVL(b.advanced_payment, 0) - a.advanced_payment)
           + a.unbilled
               AS tota
        -- THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM BEGINS
         , NVL(b.bucket_1_30, 0) AS bucket_1_30
         , NVL(b.bucket_31_60, 0) AS bucket_31_60
         , NVL(b.bucket_61_90, 0) AS bucket_61_90
         , NVL(b.bucket_91_180, 0) AS bucket_91_180
         , NVL(b.bucket_181_365, 0) AS bucket_181_365
         , NVL(b.bucket_over_365, 0) AS bucket_over_365
      FROM acct_tbl a LEFT JOIN bll_tbl b ON b.acct_id = a.acct_id;
```

This is the execution plan for the query

```
"--------------------------------------------------------------------"
"| Id  | Operation                               | Name             |"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------"
"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                  |"
"|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                         |                  |"
"|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED   | table1           |"
"|   3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | table1_IX1       |"
"|   4 |  SORT AGGREGATE                         |                  |"
"|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED   | tableX           |"
"|   6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | tableX_IX1       |"
"|   7 |    SORT AGGREGATE                       |                  |"
"|   8 |     FILTER                              |                  |"
"|   9 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | table2           |"
"|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| table3           |"
"|  11 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | table3_IX1       |"
"|  12 |  HASH JOIN OUTER                        |                  |"
"|  13 |   VIEW                                  |                  |"
"|  14 |    HASH GROUP BY                        |                  |"
"|  15 |     INDEX FULL SCAN                     | table4_IX1       |"
"|  16 |   VIEW                                  |                  |"
"|  17 |    HASH GROUP BY                        |                  |"
"|  18 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | table5           |"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

If I leave out the "offending" columns in the last select statement the the query will run in 2 minutes and the executionplan will change to the following. Which isn't much different, but the use between the full access of table 5 and Group by og table4_IX1 is opposite. Dont know if that will cause horrible efficiency.

```html
" "
"--------------------------------------------------------------------"
"| Id  | Operation                               | Name             |"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------"
"|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                  |"
"|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                         |                  |"
"|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED   | table1           |"
"|   3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | table1_IX1       |"
"|   4 |  SORT AGGREGATE                         |                  |"
"|   5 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED   | tableX           |"
"|   6 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                     | tableX_IX1       |"
"|   7 |    SORT AGGREGATE                       |                  |"
"|   8 |     FILTER                              |                  |"
"|   9 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | Table2           |"
"|  10 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| Table3           |"
"|  11 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | Table3_IX1       |"
"|  12 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                  |                  |"
"|  13 |   VIEW                                  |                  |"
"|  14 |    HASH GROUP BY                        |                  |"
"|  15 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | Table5           |"
"|  16 |   VIEW                                  |                  |"
"|  17 |    HASH GROUP BY                        |                  |"
"|  18 |     INDEX FULL SCAN                     | Table4_IX1       |"
"--------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: Where (in which tool) do you execute this query? I'm asking because in previous (4.x and earlier) Apex versions query sources where VARCHAR2(4000) so - if you entered a longer query, you had *issues*. Now it is a CLOB so no such problems any more. Therefore, I'm just guessing - maybe you hit something like that.

Comment: You can check if the execution plan changes for some reason to something horribly slow if you add those columns (although it's unlikely given the current query)

Comment: A deadlock is something quite specific; are you really seeing that or does it just take so long that the resource manager (or something) kills it? What specific error do you see, and is there any additional info in the alert log or trace logs? Also this is a query not a view, and you refer to a procedure; so it isn't entirely clear exactly when or where you see the issue...

Comment: Im not sure if it actually is a deadlock. I might also be because it takes too long to execute. It takes roughly 2.30min to execute if i leave out the last 5 selects. and if i add one of the last 5 or all of them, it will choke.

Im using oracle and pl/sql

Comment: Its oracle version 11 im trying to run it on. Don't know if that might be the problem.

Comment: "it will choke" is not a valid Oracle error message. Without the actual error(s) you get, and the execution plans for both queries in case the optimiser is doing something odd (and the exact patch level you are on might be relevant to that too), I'm not sure what you think we can do to help.

Comment: Yeah i know problem is that oracle doesnt show an error message (Ora-XXXXX) it just stops, (forcefully killed by oracle) which is why im having a hard time finding the problem myself.. 

REASON="Stop job with force called by user: 'DB_USER"

Comment: I have added the execution plan for the query into the orginal question

Comment: So it is hanging, not a deadlock, and this leads to a timeout due to some application limit we can't see? Is the problem the timeout, the session-killing mechanism or the performance?

Comment: The problem could be any of these things, it might finish if it was given enough time. But i would rarther that the performance was better. I have edited the title and inserted some more opservations i have done. I have inserted these observations in the orginal post, just  above the code section.